# Strange XML error during SqlBulkCopy

Tags: .net, xml

Regrettably it's fallen to me to fix an error in someone else's code while they're away for the holiday in spite of having only been in the job for 2 weeks! And it's a fun one as well - my understanding of what I'm working on is necessarily incomplete so I'm hoping the community can help me out a bit.

The error is occurring when we're trying to process an external XML file. The error we're getting is a standard " System.Xml.XmlException: There is an unclosed literal string " with a line number attached. But there's nothing wrong with the line specified and the line number of the error changes every time we try and process the file.

I still assumed this was a formatting error so I wrote a little console app that runs through all the xml nodes and dumps the values out to the screen, just as a way of checking that the whole document was valid. It ran through the lot and hit no errors. I introduced a deliberate syntax error just to make sure and my program caught it. So I'm pretty confident there's nothing wrong with the source XML.

Looking at the code where the error is happening it's using SQlBulkCopy which isn't something I'm familiar with. It attempts to execute a WriteToServer method with an argument of IDataReader which is a JsonPathSourceReader created with the XML data.

By the time we hit the error the code has already done a bunch of work with the Reader so the mappings also look to be correct.

Can anyone help me out even by pointing me in the right direction to try and get some more information?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: I suspect the `SqlBulkCopy` is a red-herring here, as it isn't overly concerned with xml; what happens if you just use the reader: `object[] vals = new object[reader.FieldCount]; while(reader.Next()) {reader.GetValues(vals);}` ? does it throw the same?

Comment: I have an additional problem in that I can't easily make changes or debug this as it's on live code and I don't have a dev version with the same setup that I can test. Long story. But I'll have to mock something up in a console app to answer your question - bear with me, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: A "JsonPathSourceReader" (whatever that is, but it seems to read JSON in some way) reading XML?! Maybe you should look into the implementation of that reader and find out what it's giving you.

Comment: @Matt - you might also be able to get similar information from the stacktrace; do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: @Matt - if you manage to dig something out, be sure to include "@Marc" in your comment - otherwise I won't see it...

Comment: @Marc Stack Trace looks like this: http://mattthr.blogspot.com/2010/12/stack-trace.html

Comment: @TToni fair call - I didn't realise it was an internal object at first, but it is. However whatever it is it seems to be doing it's job as it runs through a bunch of tasks before hitting this error.

Comment: @Matt - well, it looks like `Loader.Readers.XmlSourceReader.ReadRowObjects()` would be a good place to start looking - I think `SqlBulkCopy` is the *victim* here, not the cause. Since you've asserted that the xml is good, there must be something odd going on in there, perhaps how it is splitting it per row...